# How to set path to get csc.exe on AppVeyor CI

Tags: appveyor

Trying to use appveyor CI for a C++ project (Makefile) with binding in C# so I would like to be able to run csc.exe from the script line.
According to the doc https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#net-framework, I would say csc.exe must be installed somehow in the image.

i.e. need to fill the `????????????` in my [.appveyor.yml](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/mizux/dev/.appveyor.yml):

```
...
environment:
- APPVEYOR_BUILD_WORKER_IMAGE: Visual Studio 2017
...
build:
- set PATH=C:\Python36-x64;%PATH%
- where python.exe
- where /F python.exe | tools\sed.exe -n "/\".*\"/{p;q;}" | tools\sed "s/\"//g"
- set PATH=C:\????????????;%PATH%
- where csc.exe
```

I got:

```
$ set PATH=C:\Python36-x64;%PATH%
$ where python.exe
C:\Python36-x64\python.exe
C:\Python27\python.exe
$ where /F python.exe | tools\sed.exe -n "/\".*\"/{p;q;}" | tools\sed "s/\"//g"
C:\Python36-x64\python.exe
$ where csc.exe
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

ps: I put python as an example of what I would like to do for csc.exe, fsc.exe and dotnet ....
pps: why sed ? typically I would like a prompt equivalent to bash cmd `which` (i.e. only return the first one if any)

Comment: There is also GNUWin `which` to avoid the boiler plate with GNUWin `sed`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this in `appveyor.yml`:

```
after_build:
  - cmd: |
      call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
      csc.exe main.cs
```

The `VsDevCmd.bat` file will automatically set the console environment for using MS Build Tools. `main.cs` is for example. Also you can add `cl.exe` after/before with `csc.exe` for both C++/C# projects. See this article [Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply Recursively try to find it !

```
build:
- where -F -R \ csc.exe
```

possible output:

```
$ where -F -R \ csc.exe
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack5\Packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\tools\csc.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler\1.7.3\tools\arm\ilc\csc\csc.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler\1.7.3\tools\x64\ilc\csc\csc.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler\1.7.3\tools\x86\ilc\csc\csc.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackagesFallback\Microsoft.Net.Native.Compiler\2.0.2\tools\csc\csc.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe"
```

then set the path accordingly...

Comment: Agreed. Also `cd c:\ && dir /s csc.exe` will show great number of paths to `csc.exe`. And finally you can RDP and check manually: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/